# Redux (with React) - dispatching of a REQUEST action which sets loading, etc causes an additional render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, state, dispatch

Fairly straight forward question.  (I am an old developer building a React app which needs high performance and have inherited an old repo).

Most apps I see, when dispatching an API request firstly submit 1) a REQUEST then either 2) SUCCESS or FAILURE

The thing is, when you dispatch the REQUEST, it changes the state and causes any connected components to re-render.

I discovered this when trying to find out why my puppeteer tests are so flakey.  (Using material ui with rendering animations / action-ready issues etc)

So,

Why is it normal/good practice -- in Redux -- to use a REQUEST action which modifies the state?  (e.g. clears it out, sets loading:true, timestamp, whatever) etc.  If so why do this REQUEST action?  Why not skip the REQUEST action and just update on SUCCESS / FAILURE to prevent a re-render?

Or, submit the REQUEST with a non-modifying reducer?

Obviously there are use cases to clear the state on REQUEST, but when fetching something like a category page, update state on REQUEST?

Is there something I am missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Why is it normal/good practice -- in Redux -- to use a REQUEST action which modifies the state? (e.g. clears it out, sets loading:true, timestamp, whatever) etc. If so why do this REQUEST action? Why not skip the REQUEST action and just update on SUCCESS / FAILURE to prevent a re-render?

One example:
Imagine you have a component that requires the data that you need to fetch from the API. On frontend you like to have a loading bar indicator. You will only be able to show that loading bar if you know that you requested the call.

Imagine we do it without REQUEST/LOADING indicator:
If the user already has been on this page with the component invoking the request and comes again, the state (FAILURE/SUCCESS) would already have been set. That means, if the previous state was on "FAILURE" and you are rendering your component depending on this state, it will show your "FAILURE" rendering first. And then, it might be updatinng with your SUCCESS render. For the user, this will result in flickering from error message/page to the result page or the other way round what is no good UX, indeed.

Comment: I see what you mean, but the loading bar I use is a middleware which initiates on REQUEST (regardless of the reducer returns just state or modifies state) and ends on SUCCESS / FAILURE.  If FAILURE is a result, I would have a `error: true` var then render a loading bar and auto dispatch another request in such a situation.    I suppose the situation I am highlighting is limited to certain situations. e.g. a category tree:

Comment: The ugliness can be mitigated with animated transitions but still looks bad in certain places.  Not to mention the double/triple rendering which makes browser testing hard.  But, having played with it, I can see there are certain times to setstate whilst loading.  But I am finding many situations where it is far cleaner to reduce nothing on REQUEST so the UX does not flash in and out, and instead gracefully and rapidly updates based on the key{} in the front end without even a flicker....  if ERROR occurs, just throw throw out a snack bar and put in a spinner until the next SUCCESS hits?

Comment: Must admit, I am quite new to React coming from LAMP C and golang so am on a learning curve and just want to learn.  I still feel confused why some sites do this as a blanket rule and have ajax spinners everywhere when they could maintain state and update it?  if ERROR, spinner it.  I may still be missing the point but thanks for your answer.